# How to apply same behaviors on java objects?

Tags: java, android

How can I apply the same behavior of multiple class objects in java(android)? For example, in jquery it's easy because you can select all/or a specific DOM object(s)

```
    $('.div').on("mousedown",function(){
        $(this).css({"transform":"scale(0.8)"});

    });
    $('.div').on("mouseup",function(){
        $(this).css({"transform":"scale(0.9)"});

    });
```

I want to make this similar in Android , i make an XML animation and when i press a card view(i have 9) ,that view animate.I succeeded making one to animate but I don't want to apply this 9 times to all views.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using state list animators.
After creating the animation you want, just apply it to the cardview XML

Comment: Thanks , it works. I used the information from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#kotlin